# Accessing data from a .gdb file with SQL Server Integration Services (2005 or 2008)

Tags: sql-server, ssis, interbase

I have number of files in .gdb format, which I believe is associated with Borland interbase.  Does anyone know how I would go about extracting data from the using SSIS (2005 or 2008)?

Any help very much appreciated.

Ed.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution would probably be to find an ODBC or OLEDB driver for Borland Interbase files, connect it to your files, then use it as a data source in SSIS.

There appear to be several ODBC drivers for Borland Interbase. [This one](http://www.brothersoft.com/xtg-systems-interbase-odbc-driver-571.html) is free. [This one](http://www.easysoft.com/products/data_access/odbc_interbase_driver/) isn't.

An OLEDB driver (not free, although a free trial is available) can be found [here](http://www.ibprovider.com/eng/).

Comment: Borland InterBase includes an ODBC driver. You don't need a third party driver.